# Problems using Java Windowbuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, plugins, windowbuilder

I've been working toward making a Java program with a simple GUI. After a bit of research I decided on using the plugin Windowbuilder. I followed instructions online step-by-step to set up the program, but after I finished I've been getting numerous errors about the import statements (and by extent the code).

To be clear, I made sure to install the plugin for eclipse before creating the program. Everything that has been listed was auto-generated.

```
/* These are the import statemements that
 * I believe are causing the issues.
 * Eclipse says the import "org" cannot be resolved. */

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here. 
Is there another plugin that Windowbuilder requires?
I just want to experiment with visual programming.

P.S. please let me know if there is something else I should share to help diagnose and solve the issue.

Also, if there is a better/easier method to implement a primitive UI, a reference to that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have org.eclipse.swt as a Dependency in your plug-in?

Comment: @AdamHorvath I don't believe so. Nothing like that was mentioned as far as I can remember.

Comment: Is this tutorial public? Can you post a link?